# React native unable to create release build in android

Tags: android, react-native

i encounter an error when trying to build the react native. It has been quite long since the last time i build it, so please help me to fix this issue.

The change since last successful build was around adding the `react-native-camera` and `react-native-pure-jwt`. So now this is the error detail:

```
PS D:\react-app\android> ./gradlew assembleRelease

> Configure project :app
Reading env from: .env.production

> Configure project :react-native-pure-jwt
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.1) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.4.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Configure project :rn-secure-storage
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.4.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-camera:compileMlkitReleaseAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':react-native-camera:mlkitReleaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-label:12.+.
     Versions that do not match:
       - 18.0.0
       - 17.0.2
       - 16.2.0
       - 15.0.0
     Required by:
         project :react-native-camera > com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:19.0.3
   > Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut:12.+.
     Versions that do not match:
       - 17.0.0
       - 16.0.0
       - 15.0.1
       - 15.0.0
       - 11.0.4
       - + 15 more
     Required by:
         project :react-native-camera > com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2
         project :react-native-camera > com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common:17.0.0
   > Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:12.+.
     Versions that do not match:
       - 17.0.0
       - 16.0.1
       - 15.0.1
       - 15.0.0
     Required by:
         project :react-native-camera > com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2
   > Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-phenotype:12.+.
     Versions that do not match:
       - 17.0.0
       - 16.0.0
       - 15.0.1
       - 15.0.0
     Required by:
         project :react-native-camera > com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-common:17.0.0
```

this is the `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "androidapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "release-android": "cd android && ./gradlew assemebleRelease",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "log-android": "react-native log-android",
    "build-android": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
    "lint:fix": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json --fix",
    "adb-reverse": "adb reverse tcp:4000 tcp:4000"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/react-native-action-sheet": "^3.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
    "@types/react-native-qrcode": "^0.2.2",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.1",
    "@types/uuid": "^3.4.5",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",
    "react-native-biometrics": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-config": "^0.11.7",
    "react-native-crypto-js": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-pure-jwt": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^5.1.2",
    "react-native-rsa-native": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.7.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.12.0",
    "rn-secure-storage": "^2.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.19.0",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.2",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.18",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.2",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.60.8",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.9.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.2.2",
    "husky": "^3.0.4",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.13",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**EDIT 1:** Adding `build.gradle`
`android/build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        jcenter()
    }
    subprojects {
      project.configurations.all {
          resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
              if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                      && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                  details.useVersion "26.+"
              }
              if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
              && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') && !details.requested.name.contains('play-services-stats')) {
                  details.useVersion "12.+"
              }
              if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
              && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') && details.requested.name.contains('play-services-stats')) {
                  details.useVersion "+"
              }
          }
      }
    }
}
```

`android/app/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
  debug: ".env.development",
  release: ".env.production",
  anothercustombuild: ".env",
]

apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.reactapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
          storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
          storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
          keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
          keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.+"

    if (enableHermes) {
      def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermesvm/android/";
      debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
      releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
      implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Comment: Add your build.gradle file from Android module.

Comment: ok, there the ```build.gradle```

Comment: Where do you mention react-native-camera in gradle file ?

Comment: hm? i dont know what you mean? btw if you are talking about the linking, the react native 0.60 no longer need to link

Comment: no you must need it to be mentioned in gradle if you want to use any external module or dependency.

Comment: oh btw im not really that good in react native yet, so can you please help? i dont get what you mean here

Comment: check [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/installation.md#mostly-automatic-install-with-react-native).
Link required.

Answer (score 0):

***Using Logcat CLI to determine the issue***
Connect your device to your machine (ensure USB debugging is ON) and run the following command on your terminal.

```
adb logcat '*:E'
```

Find out more about Logcat CLI syntax [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat).
After running the logcat tool to log system logs, I had two issues that were causing the application to crash.

1. **couldn’t find DSO to load: libjsexecutor.so**
   I solved libjsexecutor.so error by adding enableVmCleanup: false in build.gradle file inside project.ext.react array as mentioned in the GitHub comment here.

   ```
    project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,     // clean and rebuild if changing
    enableVmCleanup: false, //this
   ```

   ]
2. **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script.**
   To solve this issue follow the steps below

   - Remove index.android.bundle from android/app/src/main/assets if the file already exists or just run the following command (ensure you’re on your project’s root directory).

   rm android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle

For generating your android bundle run the command given below, this will generate index.android.bundle file inside android/app/src/main/assets

```
    npx react-native bundle \
--platform android \
--dev false \
--entry-file index.js \
--bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
```

-Now run the following command to generate a release build

```
    cd android
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assembleRelease
```